# LeJOS NXT movement in centimeters

Tags: java, robotics, lejos-nxj

I just started learning LeJOS programming and have a small probelm. I understand that I can measure movement distance in seconds and degrees. Is it possible to measure distance in centimeters, for instance.
If yes, then how?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that your robot uses wheels to enable it to move. If you can obtain the amount of degrees that your wheel turns, you can use the [Arc Length Formula](http://math.about.com/od/formulas/ss/surfaceareavol_9.htm) to obtain the linear distance that your wheel moved.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using wheels it depends on the radius of your wheels. The distance a wheel travels is directly related to the circumference of the wheel.

Say we have 2 wheels, one with a 2cm radius and the other with a 4cm radius. If we allow each wheel to do a complete (360degrees) rotation the robot will have traveled the complete circumference of the wheel.

@2cm radius distance=12.6cm
@4cm radius distance=25.1cm

But then how do we calculate the distance if we only move a fraction of a complete rotation or more then 1 rotation?

Use the formula Distance = 2 * PI * Radius * (Degrees / 360)

You could also use the

```
import lejos.robotics.navigation.Move;
...
float distance = Move.convertAngleToDistance(/*float*/angle,/*float*/turnRadius);
```